# How to add a blog filter bar without paying money. (example inside)

Tags: filters, blog-page

[image: blogfilter]

Hello, I saw this type of blog filter on a website and I really liked it. I was hoping I could add something similar on my site but I haven't found a way to do so without a plugin. If anyone has experience in this, please share, thanks! :^)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The filter that you see is not really a filter, it's just menu links.
Each menu item such as the link that says "Support" will show posts that are in the "Support" category.

First go to WP > Posts > Categories and create a category called "Support". Then add posts to that category.

Go to WP > Appearance > Menus and add the category called "Support" into your menu. Users will now see all posts of "Support" when they click that menu link.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. What I have done is I created a new menu and put in my categories. My question now is, can I make it that the menu doesn't show where the primary menu shows on the header but it shows right above the blog? I am using elementor aswell and I'm wondering if I will have any issues adding the menu because of elementor. Dont know if I can post links but https://gyazo.com/e00c8909ebf5c60e7f1ea31000a8fff1 . I want the menu to show just below the big BLOG, Thanks

Comment: Inside of Elementor you can use the element for the menu. Then insert the menu using elementor. There are different ways to insert menus, one is elementor elements, the other is widgets and the Navigation widget, and third is regular text with links.

Comment: I see I see, thats pretty cool, thank you. I was wondering what you could do with wordpress elements in elementor. Ive created text as my 4 categories, how do I link them so that they dont throw you in a different page but just categorise the posts?

Comment: Each category in WordPress is a page. Therefore when you link a user to click on a category it will go to a different page, the page of that category.

Comment: Alright, sounds good. Thank you alot!

Comment: Please upvote the answer if it has helped you.